# I'm about to be promoted, but I'm afraid that HR will pull some stunts to prevent salary increasing as much as it should

Tags: salary, human-resources, promotion

Our team has grown a lot within the past 1 1/2 years, from 3 people to now 20 people, in two different locations.

Since top level management thinks that what we're doing is really gonna grow a lot bigger in the future, we're now being split off into our own legal entity, which will be a 100% child company of my current employer. My current manager will function as the CEO of that new company.

I've been open about wanting to have more responsibility and he's recently told me, that I'll be promoted to be the manager of one of the two teams (basically, I'll be responsible for one of our two locations, with round about 10-15 people).

My problem is that the HR of my current employer (the future parent company) seems to like blocking people from actually getting ahead. I had a talk with them about half a year ago, where I also expressed that I'd like to take on more responsibility, but they just gave me the usual: "Well, you've only been in the company for little over a year now, it'd be very unusual for you to even start a personal development plan at this point." and "We could get something going, and that would probably take you 2 years to complete".

Meaning: I'll be stuck for at least two more years in my current position without any salary increase.

My current manager himself has been 100% supportive of me, and I feel like he really wants me to get ahead as well.

Something I also need to include here: We're working as part of a collective agreement, which sets salary ranges etc. for all employees, depending on what they do.

My question is: According to my new position, I should receive a salary of X, based on that salary range. I feel like HR will argue stuff like "lacking experience", the current budget situation or some other bullshit to prevent me from actually being paid what I'm worth. How can I prevent that?

Comment: I think the OP is just distrustful of HR, and not the entire company...it reads as if they like working there and they have a manager who wants them to go somewhere in their career. Suggesting to quit, although the most common of all suggestions on theworkplace, is a terrible one and *not* helpful.

Comment: Why borrow trouble?  See what happens and, if you don't like the outcome, get something else going and remember that your notice will take two weeks to complete.

Comment: @morbo, but HR is working for the company, and makes what company wants, don't you think?

Comment: There is a limit to what should be tolerated from a company, and HR or ones manager making up bs to prevent ones raise is not one of them.

Comment: @Blrfl OP wants to steer things towards a favourable outcome instead of just waiting to see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

"I feel like it's going to rain today." doesn't mean it's going to rain today.

Everything you've stated is conjecture on your part. My advice would be to lobby for the raise you think you deserve for this new position and if you don't get what you ask for then consider either stepping down from this position or find a job elsewhere. There really are no other choices.

Comment: Excellent advice, as usual. I would add, OP, that when lobbying, you try to do so objectively and ask your current manager for a reference. If S/he thinks you're a good fit for the position, then HR will have a harder time arguing that you're not. Take the low end of salary band X for that position (or more if you can get it) and keep notes of your achievements over the next 6/12 months for use at the next review.